# Redirect PHP to HTML, but have HTML point to PHP

Tags: .htaccess

Consider the following rules

```
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ index.html [R=301]
```

I want `.html` to use the `.php` file, but I want the url to have the `.html` extension always.

The above rule creates a redirection loop. What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either check against the actual request, or prevent looping entirely.

1. Option 1, check against request:

   ```
   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ index.html [R=301]
   ```

   This makes it so if the actual request isn't `index.php`, the redirect won't happen.
2. Option 2, prevent rewrite engine from looping entirely. Add this to the top of your htaccess file:

   ```
   RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
   RewriteRule ^ - [L]
   ```

   The downside with this is that you may have rules that actually want to loop.

Comment: Thanks, mind explaining what `^[A-Z]{3,9}\` does in the first solution?

Comment: @stevether The `%{THE_REQUEST}` var is literally the first line of the HTTP request, e.g. `GET /index.php HTTP/1.1`, and the `^[A-Z]{3,9}` matches the `GET` part, which is the "method" and can be anywhere between 3 to 9 characters long. If you only care about GET/POST, you can alternatively change that to `(GET|POST)`.